# can you use the same account on 2 different cd keys on Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

So i got an account with me and my dads characters on it and well i'm planning on getting another cd key so i can play with him, but I don't know if thats possible even with 2 computers on the same account at the same time.

IF not is there a way too transfer character on a different account?

Comment: Sorry johnny seems